# Microsoft Graph OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound when using mail.send

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I would like to use Microsoft Graph and this works:

```
await graphClient.Users["xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx"]
                .Request()
                .GetAsync();
```

And this throws the OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound error:

```
await graphClient.Users["xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx"]
                .SendMail(message, false)
                .Request()
                .PostAsync()
```

I authenticate as an application with my client id, tenant id and secret.

I have set mail permissions in my app registration and the user is assigned.

[Graph permissions with admin consent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AljOp.png)

I have tried to define the scope as "https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.send/.default" but then I get this error: MsalServiceException: AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.send was not found in the tenant...

I have also tried adding a new user to my app registration but that gives the same error.

My AAD account does have a Microsoft 365 Family subscription and I have an Azure trial account.

What else should I check? Thank you!

Comment: Please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound` comes mostly when there is no mailbox present.

You should have the Exchange Online License to work with `SendMail` endpoint because this endpoint is on exchange workload. And also, as you have specified the permissions in Azure AD you can simply add the scope as `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` which pulls all the given permissions in Azure AD and add to your token.

Make sure you are using the Client Credential Flow(Application context) to get the App token.

Comment: No mailbox present was the problem in my case! I have tried again with a Azure AD with the `Azure AD for Office 365` license (included with a Microsoft 365 Business Standard subscription). It works! I was already using the client credential flow so that was not the problem and I'm using the scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that my answer helped you :)